# Length character count using recursive function

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I'm trying to create a recursive function that could count the characters of a string, but I don't know why my code is crashing my system. I don't have any more ideas.
Any suggestions:

```
long slength (const char ntca[])
{
    int length = 0;

    if (ntca[length] == '\0'){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return  slength(ntca)+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do hope this is purely academic ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current code calls `slength` for the same buffer recursively.  This will continue until the stack overflows.

You need to reduce the buffer by one character as well as adding 1 to the length count for each recursive call

```
return  slength(ntca+1)+1;
//                  ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

It's crashing because you're not shortening the string.  The line should read

```
return  slength(ntca+1)+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to declare the local variable. The function can be written simpler

```
size_t slength( const char s[] )
{
    return ( *s == '\0' ? 0 : 1 + slength( s + 1 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the recursive call. If the length of `ntca` is not zero, then this function calls itself *with exactly the same argument*. This causes an endless recursion which crashes the stack.

You should work through your algorithm with pencil and paper before you try it in code.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you use recursion, you have to make a recursive call on a smaller problem size. In your code, you call the function to the same array (or rather, the same pointer to the first element in the array), rather than the pointer to the next element in the array.

However, it's recommended you don't use recursion in C++. Also, since this is such a common thing, there is a `strlen()` defined in the `<cstring>` header. Don't define your own functions if there is already a known one in the C++ standard library.

Comment: 'it's recommended you don't use recursion in C++'... really?  By who, why?

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with using recursion in C++ (that is, it is not recommended to not use it).  That said, you use it for appropriate problems.  This problem is easily handled by a simple loop, so introducing recursion adds a lot of extra overhead that is not needed.

Comment: @forsvarir it's not recommended in _certain_ _cases_ I should say. There are cases when if you're dealing with recursive data structures that you should use recursion. Otherwise, without optimizations, it could make code a lot slower.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reduce the answer size in your recursion. In other words, try to reduce the size of your string (ntca) in order to stop infinite recursion. Or try to add a parameter to control the recursion like this:

```
long slength (const char ntca[], int n) //Look from n to the end of string for '\0'
{
    if (ntca[n] == '\0')
        return n; //the index of char '\0' indicates the length of string 
    else
        return  slength(ntca, n+1); //go, check the next char
}
```

So you always have to call this function as follows:
x = slength(s, 0)